# Undefined Values from Json POST

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, typeahead, bloodhound

I have this script

```
<script>

    var engine = new Bloodhound({       
        remote: {
            url: '/my/GetAllTags',
            ajax: {
                type: 'POST'
            }
        },        
        datumTokenizer: function (d) {
            return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d.val);
        },
        queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace
    });

    engine.initialize();

    $('#tokenfield-typeahead').tokenfield({
        typeahead: [null, { dispalyKey: 'val', source: engine.ttAdapter() }]
    });


</script>
```

Where my controller which returns the values is the following

```
[HttpPost]
        public JsonResult GetAllTags()
        {
            List<Models.Tags.MTag> Tag_List = new List<Models.Tags.MTag>();
            Tag_List.Add(new Models.Tags.MTag { Tag_id = 1, Tag_name = "Test 1" });
            Tag_List.Add(new Models.Tags.MTag { Tag_id = 1, Tag_name = "Test 2" });
            var TAGS = Tag_List;
            return Json(TAGS.Select(t => new { val = t.Tag_name }));

        }
```

Where the model is very simple and has only two fields

```
 public class MTag
    {
        public Int64 Tag_id { get; set; }
        public string Tag_name { get; set; }
    }
```

My results are `UNDEFINED` as shown in the following image

[image]

I am not sure what am i doing wrong, any idea

cheers

Comment: Should that be `displayKey:` not `dispalyKey:`

Comment: Well to start with you have misspelled `dispalyKey`.  Should be `displayKey`

Comment: Thanks, guys - It now displays data but I am unable to `select it` and it also not `filtering out`

Comment: Filtering is not happening because you don't have filtering logic in GetAllTags method in c#. It should be changed to GetAllTags(string input) and then return list by filtering based on input value.

Comment: Ok i managed to filter it now using `return Json(TAGS.Where(t => t.Tag_name.Contains(keyword)).Select(t => new { id = t.Tag_id, val = t.Tag_name }), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);` But i am still unable to select it when i press enter or click using the mouse